# Using non-trivial REST API and Ember

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

We're new to Ember, and our intended (ember-cli) app first works by opening a project (which we can think of a JSON object), and then acting on various sections of that project with various functions. We have this "pick your project first" approach neatly encapsulated in a Django REST api structure, e.g.

1. `/projects/` lists all projects
2. `/projects/1/` gives information about project 1
3. `/projects/1/sectionA/` list all elements in sectionA of project 1
4. `/projects/1/sectionA/2/` gives information about element 2 of sectionA in project 1
5. `/projects/1/sectionA/2/sectionB/...` and so on.

We made relatively good progress with the first two points in Ember using ember-data and `this.store('project').find(...)` etc. However, we've come unstuck trying to add further to our url (e.g. points 3., 4., and 5.). I believe our issues come from routing and handling multiple models (e.g. project and sectionA).

**The question**: *what is the best way to structure the routes in Ember.js to match a non-trivial REST API, and use ember-data similarly?*

**Comments:**

1. the "Ember way", and stuff working out of the box is preferred. Custom adapters and `.getJSON` might work, but we're not sure if we'll then lose out on what Ember offers.
2. we want the choice of project to affect the main app template. E.g. if a project does not have "sectionA", then a link to "sectionA" is not displayed in the main app. And, if the project does have "sectionA", we need the link to be to e.g. "/project/1/sectionA", i.e. dependant on the project open.
3. This seems similar to handling users (i.e. first I must "pick a user" and then continue), where the problem is solved outside of the URL (and is similar to using sessions as we have done in the past). However, we specifically want the project ID to be inside the URL, to remain stateless.

**Bonus questions (if relevant):**

1. how would we structure the models? Do we need to use `hasMany`/`belongsTo` and, if so, is this equivalent to just loading the whole project JSON in the first place?
2. can ember-data handle such complex requests? I.e. "give me item 2 from sectionA of project 1"? Can it do this "in one go", or do there have to be nested queries (i.e. "first give me project 1" and then from this "give me sectionA" and then from this "give me item 1")?

Finally, apologies if this is documented well somewhere. We've spent nearly a week trying to figure this out and have tried our best to find resources -- it's possible we just don't know what we're looking for.

Comment: I think this one will be a good thing to read: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/nested-urls-for-ember-datas-restadapter-proposal/5290/13 - you've got Tom Dale and Stefan Penner involved in the thread

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will be a good thing to read: discuss.emberjs.com/t/… - you've got Tom Dale and Stefan Penner involved in the thread

My suggestion would be to change it to query params:

```
/projects?id=1&selectionA=a&selectionB=b
```

then, you won't have such problems. And yes, you can still use all the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` fields.

If there's anything unclear, I'll provide you with a longer answer (if I'm able to).

Comment: I'm afraid query parameters are probably out. Two reasons: (1), our API is already constructed using e.g. `/projects/1/sectionA/a/...` etc., and (2) we might run into issues with duplicate parameters e.g. currently I could do `/projects?date=20150204` and `/projects/1/sectionA?date=20150204` ... with your approach of using only query parameters, this might get confusing as is `date` being used to filter `/projects` or `/sectionA`? (Yes, it might still work, but I think my point is valid?). Reading that above link suggests we might have to avoid ember-data for now. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ember-api-actions](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions) and [ember-data-actions](https://github.com/davewasmer/ember-data-actions) also [ember-data-url-templates](https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates)

Here's a few more resources from a blog I found. [ember-data-working-with-custom-api-endpoints](http://blog.ksol.fr/ember-data-working-with-custom-api-endpoints/) and [ember-data-working-with-nested-api-resources](http://blog.ksol.fr/ember-data-working-with-nested-api-resources/)